# jquery blockUI message moving to top inside accordion when a tab is opened

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, blockui, jquery-blockui

I have a no of webpages which involve display of widgets (majorly built on highcharts jquery). Generally a widget shows a loading swivel before data is fetched and this swivel comes up in center of that screen/widget. 
On one page, I have an accordion with a couple of tabs on it (tab 1 open by default and swivel comes in center before data loads up on it). Clicking a button on tab 1 opens the tab 2 of accordion. Before data is shown on the tab2, the swivel comes up on tab 2. 
Problem here is the moment I click on tab1 button, tab 2 opens (sliding up) and the swivel is shown on top inside that div. (moving sliding up). I need to show that in center.

The css used for this and all the other apps is centralized. So answers mentioned on internet couldn't be incorporated.

the jquery code for the events for click on button etc. is written in a central and separate js file. I tried attaching a mouseout/mouseleave event on the export button and then checking if the mouse is hovering my submenu. If it's not, then close the submenu. This works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

The text of generated html is

```
<div class="blockUI" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;"></div>
**<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockElement" style="z-index: 1011; position: absolute; ***top: 0px***; left: 351.5px;"><img src="../../Apps/Images/loading.gif"></div>**
```

the underlined atttribute (top:0px) causes the problem. I checked my css. This has not been set anywhere.

The CSS of last div is

```
element.style {
    z-index: 1011;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 351.5px;
}
div.blockMsg {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 40%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    color: #FF0000;
    cursor: wait;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
```

The blockdiv is loaded in the initial moment when the div (to be hidden) starts expanding. At that time, it is by default in center. But then since accordion tab 2 is opening, the div height starts increasing and the block div still remains on top....
Any help is highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can position: fixed; use for your code rather than absolute